# C++: Get address from member function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I need am writing an operator== function that will need to compare two member function pointers and check to see if they point to the same function. I initially tried to do it like this:

```
typedef void(EventListenerClass::*EventHandler)(const Event&);
struct EventListener
{
    EventListenerClass *_listener = NULL;
    EventHandler _handler = NULL;
    inline bool operator== (const EventListener& other) const 
    { return addressof(_listener->*_handler) == addressof(other._listener->*_handler); };
};
```

But this gives me the following message:

> Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

I found a potential solution [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html), which i will quote below:

> In C++, pointer to member functions (PMFs) are implemented using a
>   wide pointer of sorts to handle all the possible call mechanisms; the
>   PMF needs to store information about how to adjust the ‘this’ pointer,
>   and if the function pointed to is virtual, where to find the vtable,
>   and where in the vtable to look for the member function. If you are
>   using PMFs in an inner loop, you should really reconsider that
>   decision. If that is not an option, you can extract the pointer to the
>   function that would be called for a given object/PMF pair and call it
>   directly inside the inner loop, to save a bit of time.
>
> The syntax for this extension is
>
> ```
>  extern A a;
>  extern int (A::*fp)();
>  typedef int (*fptr)(A *);
>
>  fptr p = (fptr)(a.*fp);
> ```

I tried adapting this solution to my code as follows:

```
extern EventListenerClass a;
extern int (EventListenerClass::*fp)();
typedef int(*fptr)(EventListenerClass *);

fptr p = (fptr)(a.*fp);
```

But this just gave me the exact same error message as before. Can anyone tell me how i can compare these two member function pointers?

Comment: Why do you need to compare the _address_ of the member function? That is the same for any given class type. Are you trying to figure out if someone is using a different class as a handler?

Comment: @RollenD'Souza I need to check if the two listeners are the same so that i can accept a listener as an argument and see if an identical one already exists. I would like to do this by comparing the addresses of the two EventListenerClasses, as well as the address of the two EventHandlers. I figure that if two listeners both reference the same instance of EventListenerClass, as well as the same member function within it, then they must be identical.

Comment: "I figure that if two listeners both reference the same instance of EventListenerClass,..." How is that not sufficient? The same class instance could listen to the same event using two distinct member functions? Is this to deal with different classes in the same inheritance tree handling the same event but in different methods? Or something more complicated? I ask because the idea of comparing member pointers is shiver-worthy.

Comment: @RollenD'Souza "The same class instance could listen to the same event using two distinct member functions?" Yes. The system i have actually works right now, but because i can't compare member function pointers there is currently no way to remove an event listener after it has been registered.

Comment: Hmm, i would suggest using a wrapper class (token) for registration to get around this...but.... have you used the extension argument, quoting from your source `You must specify -Wno-pmf-conversions to use this extension.`

Comment: @RollenD'Souza No, i must have missed that part. Let me try that and see if it works.

Comment: @RollenD'Souza I didn't realize that the extension was only for the GNU compiler. I'm using Visual Studio, so i don't think it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72704/discussion-between-rollen-dsouza-and-android927).